# audio not offset with video in PIP using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a pip video from two separate sources while keeping the audio from both clips and delaying the pip video x number of seconds. I have successfully done it but sometimes the pip video is delayed/offset the correct time but the audio from the same clip starts immediately at the beginning. if it was consistent, I could debug it further but half the time it offsets properly, other times it doesn't.
I have tried converting both videos beforehand to various formats to try and eliminate a file/codec issue.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Here is my command that works part of the time.
I am a novice using ffmpeg so this has been a challenge getting this far.

ffmpeg.exe -y -i "path to main video.mp4" -itsoffset 104 -i "path to pip video.mp4" -filter_complex "[1]scale=iw*0.3333:ih*0.3333 [pip]; [0][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-5[v];[1:a]adelay=104000|104000[a1];[0:a][a1]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac ".\Output video.mp4"

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you're using `itsoffset`, use `aresample=async=1:first_pts=0` for audio, not adelay.

Comment: I took another look at adelay and altered it and it seemed to work fine but I also switched my itsoffset to tpad based on another suggestion. Thanks for the tip, I will give the aresample a look.

Here is the current command as of right now.

`ffmpeg.exe -y -i "main.mp4" -i "pip.mp4" -filter_complex "[1]format=yuva420p,tpad=start_duration=70.5:color=black@0,scale=iw*0.3333:ih*0.3333 [pip]; [0][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h/2-overlay_h/2[v];[1:a]adelay=70500:all=true[a1];[0:a][a1]amerge[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac ".\\Output.mp4"`